# numpy recordarray with times?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, recarray

I'm trying to read an `XML` file into a `NumPy` record array.  Times are in Zulu time, `u'2013-06-06T17:47:38Z'`, and the other columns are `floats`.

The times and the `floats` can both be converted into `NumPy` arrays. However, if I try to make a `recordarray`, it fails in a variety of ways (which probably indicate that I don't know how to create record array):

```
In [124]: dataarr = np.array(zip(*[datadict[k] for k in keys]),
   .....:                     dtype=[(k,dtypes[k]) for k in keys])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-124-d59123796cfa>", line 2, in <module>
    dtype=[(k,dtypes[k]) for k in keys])
ValueError: Cannot create a NumPy datetime other than NaT with generic units

In [125]: dataarr = np.array([datadict[k] for k in keys],
                    dtype=[(k,dtypes[k]) for k in keys])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-125-ee9077bf1961>", line 2, in <module>
    dtype=[(k,dtypes[k]) for k in keys])
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object

In [126]: dataarr = np.array([datadict[k] for k in keys],
                    dtype=[dtypes[k] for k in keys])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-126-a456052bdfd4>", line 2, in <module>
    dtype=[dtypes[k] for k in keys])
TypeError: data type not understood

In [127]: dtypes
Out[127]: {'altitude': 'float', 'distance': 'float', 'time': 'datetime64'}
```

**What is the proper approach for creating a `recordarray` including times?**

(`keys` is a list, `datadict` and `dtype` are dicts)

Comment: possible duplicate of [numpy datetime64 in recarray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618499/numpy-datetime64-in-recarray)

Comment: I also recall a comment going by on the matplotlib list that numpy + datetime types was still in flux/buggy.

Comment: @askewchan: I don't think this is a duplicate, since my solution was to *not* use `datetime[D]`.

Comment: @tcaswell - it might help to link that comment.  However, since I was able to solve this specific problem with the answer below, it probably isn't too buggy for some purposes.

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2199 <- discussion at end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops, figured it out using [numpy datetime64 in recarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618499/numpy-datetime64-in-recarray?rq=1)

I tried using `datetime[D]`, which failed:

```
In [19]: dtypes
Out[19]: {'altitude': 'float', 'distance': 'float', 'time': 'datetime64[D]'}

In [20]: dataarr = np.array(zip(*[datadict[k] for k in keys]),
                    dtype=[(k,dtypes[k]) for k in keys])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-20-d59123796cfa>", line 2, in <module>
    dtype=[(k,dtypes[k]) for k in keys])
TypeError: Cannot cast NumPy timedelta64 scalar from metadata [s] to [D] according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

but `datetime[s]` works:

```
In [22]: dtypes
Out[22]: {'altitude': 'float', 'distance': 'float', 'time': 'datetime64[s]'}

In [23]: dataarr = np.array(zip(*[datadict[k] for k in keys]),
                    dtype=[(k,dtypes[k]) for k in keys])
```