# Sorting numpy array on multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I am trying to sort the following array on column1, then column2 and then column3

```
[['2008' '1' '23' 'AAPL' 'Buy' '100']
 ['2008' '1' '30' 'AAPL' 'Sell' '100']
 ['2008' '1' '23' 'GOOG' 'Buy' '100']
 ['2008' '1' '30' 'GOOG' 'Sell' '100']
 ['2008' '9' '8' 'GOOG' 'Buy' '100']
 ['2008' '9' '15' 'GOOG' 'Sell' '100']
 ['2008' '5' '1' 'XOM' 'Buy' '100']
 ['2008' '5' '8' 'XOM' 'Sell' '100']]
```

I used the following code:

```
    idx=np.lexsort((order_array[:,2],order_array[:,1],order_array[:,0]))
    order_array=order_array[idx]
```

The resultant array is

```
[['2008' '1' '23' 'AAPL' 'Buy' '100']
 ['2008' '1' '23' 'GOOG' 'Buy' '100']
 ['2008' '1' '30' 'AAPL' 'Sell' '100']
 ['2008' '1' '30' 'GOOG' 'Sell' '100']
 ['2008' '5' '1' 'XOM' 'Buy' '100']
 ['2008' '5' '8' 'XOM' 'Sell' '100']
 ['2008' '9' '15' 'GOOG' 'Sell' '100']
 ['2008' '9' '8' 'GOOG' 'Buy' '100']]
```

The problem is that the last two rows are wrong. The correct array should have the last row as the second last one. I have tried everything but am not able to understand why this is happening. Will appreciate some help.

I am using the following code for obtaining order_array.

```
 for i in ….
    x= ldt_timestamps[i] # this is a list of timestamps
    s_sym=……
    list=[int(x.year),int(x.month),int(x.day),s_sym,'Buy',100]   
    rows_list.append(list) 

 order_array=np.array(rows_list)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a 2D numpy array by multiple axes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706605/sorting-a-2d-numpy-array-by-multiple-axes)  Use that answer, but use a dtype that makes sense for your data (not all strings), e.g. `dt = dt=[('y',np.uint32),('m',np.uint32),('d',np.uint32),('sym','S4'),('bs','S4'),('huh',np.uint32)]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tldr: NumPy shines when doing numerical calculations on numerical arrays. Although it is possible (see below) NumPy is not well suited for this. You're probably better off using Pandas.

---

**The cause of the problem:**

The values are being sorted *as strings*. You need to sort them as `ints`.

```
In [7]: sorted(['15', '8'])
Out[7]: ['15', '8']

In [8]: sorted([15, 8])
Out[8]: [8, 15]
```

This happened because `order_array` contains strings. You need to convert those strings to `ints` where appropriate.

Converting dtypes from string-dtype to numerical dtype requires allocating space for a new array. Therefore, you would probably be better off revising the way you are creating `order_array` from the beginning.

Interestingly, even though you converted the values to ints, when you call

```
order_array = np.array(rows_list)
```

NumPy by default creates a *homogenous* array. In a homogeneous array every value has a same dtype. So NumPy tried to find the common denominator among all your
values and chose a string dtype, thwarting the effort you put into converting the strings to ints!

You can check the dtype for yourself by inspecting `order_array.dtype`:

```
In [42]: order_array = np.array(rows_list)

In [43]: order_array.dtype
Out[43]: dtype('|S4')
```

Now, how do we fix this?

---

**Using an object dtype:**

The simplest way is to use an 'object' dtype

```
In [53]: order_array = np.array(rows_list, dtype='object')

In [54]: order_array
Out[54]: 
array([[2008, 1, 23, AAPL, Buy, 100],
       [2008, 1, 30, AAPL, Sell, 100],
       [2008, 1, 23, GOOG, Buy, 100],
       [2008, 1, 30, GOOG, Sell, 100],
       [2008, 9, 8, GOOG, Buy, 100],
       [2008, 9, 15, GOOG, Sell, 100],
       [2008, 5, 1, XOM, Buy, 100],
       [2008, 5, 8, XOM, Sell, 100]], dtype=object)
```

The problem here is that `np.lexsort` or `np.sort` do not work on arrays of
dtype `object`. To get around that problem, you could sort the `rows_list`
before creating `order_list`:

```
In [59]: import operator

In [60]: rows_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0,1,2))
Out[60]: 
[(2008, 1, 23, 'AAPL', 'Buy', 100),
 (2008, 1, 23, 'GOOG', 'Buy', 100),
 (2008, 1, 30, 'AAPL', 'Sell', 100),
 (2008, 1, 30, 'GOOG', 'Sell', 100),
 (2008, 5, 1, 'XOM', 'Buy', 100),
 (2008, 5, 8, 'XOM', 'Sell', 100),
 (2008, 9, 8, 'GOOG', 'Buy', 100),
 (2008, 9, 15, 'GOOG', 'Sell', 100)]

order_array = np.array(rows_list, dtype='object')
```

A better option would be to combine the first three columns into datetime.date objects:

```
import operator
import datetime as DT

for i in ...:
    seq = [DT.date(int(x.year), int(x.month), int(x.day)) ,s_sym, 'Buy', 100]   
    rows_list.append(seq)
rows_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0,1,2))        
order_array = np.array(rows_list, dtype='object')

In [72]: order_array
Out[72]: 
array([[2008-01-23, AAPL, Buy, 100],
       [2008-01-30, AAPL, Sell, 100],
       [2008-01-23, GOOG, Buy, 100],
       [2008-01-30, GOOG, Sell, 100],
       [2008-09-08, GOOG, Buy, 100],
       [2008-09-15, GOOG, Sell, 100],
       [2008-05-01, XOM, Buy, 100],
       [2008-05-08, XOM, Sell, 100]], dtype=object)
```

Even though this is simple, I don't like NumPy arrays of dtype object.
You get neither the speed nor the memory space-saving gains of NumPy arrays with
native dtypes. At this point you might find working with a Python list of lists
faster and syntactically easier to deal with.

---

**Using a structured array:**

A more NumPy-ish solution which still offers speed and memory benefits is
to use a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#module-numpy.doc.structured_arrays) (as opposed to homogeneous array). To make a
structured array with `np.array` you'll need to supply a dtype explicitly:

```
dt = [('year', '<i4'), ('month', '<i4'), ('day', '<i4'), ('symbol', '|S8'),
      ('action', '|S4'), ('value', '<i4')]
order_array = np.array(rows_list, dtype=dt)

In [47]: order_array.dtype
Out[47]: dtype([('year', '<i4'), ('month', '<i4'), ('day', '<i4'), ('symbol', '|S8'), ('action', '|S4'), ('value', '<i4')])
```

To sort the structured array you could use the `sort` method:

```
order_array.sort(order=['year', 'month', 'day'])
```

---

To work with structured arrays, you'll need to know about some differences between homogenous and structured arrays:

Your original homogenous array was 2-dimensional. In contrast, all
structured arrays are 1-dimensional:

```
In [51]: order_array.shape
Out[51]: (8,)
```

If you index the structured array with an int or iterate through the array, you
get back rows:

```
In [52]: order_array[3]
Out[52]: (2008, 1, 30, 'GOOG', 'Sell', 100)
```

With homogeneous arrays you can access the columns with `order_array[:, i]`
Now, with a structured array, you access them by name: e.g. `order_array['year']`.

---

**Or, use Pandas:**

If you can install [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), I think you might be happiest working with a Pandas DataFrame:

```
In [73]: df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list, columns=['date', 'symbol', 'action', 'value'])
In [75]: df.sort(['date'])
Out[75]: 
         date symbol action  value
0  2008-01-23   AAPL    Buy    100
2  2008-01-23   GOOG    Buy    100
1  2008-01-30   AAPL   Sell    100
3  2008-01-30   GOOG   Sell    100
6  2008-05-01    XOM    Buy    100
7  2008-05-08    XOM   Sell    100
4  2008-09-08   GOOG    Buy    100
5  2008-09-15   GOOG   Sell    100
```

Pandas has useful functions for aligning timeseries by dates, filling in missing
values, grouping and aggregating/transforming rows or columns.

---

Typically it is more useful to have a single date column instead of three integer-valued columns for the year, month, day.

If you need the year, month, day as separate columns for the purpose of outputing, to say csv, then you can replace the date column with year, month, day columns like this:

```
In [33]: df = df.join(df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x.year, x.month, x.day], index=['year', 'month', 'day'])))

In [34]: del df['date']

In [35]: df
Out[35]: 
  symbol action  value  year  month  day
0   AAPL    Buy    100  2008      1   23
1   GOOG    Buy    100  2008      1   23
2   AAPL   Sell    100  2008      1   30
3   GOOG   Sell    100  2008      1   30
4    XOM    Buy    100  2008      5    1
5    XOM   Sell    100  2008      5    8
6   GOOG    Buy    100  2008      9    8
7   GOOG   Sell    100  2008      9   15
```

Or, if you have no use for the 'date' column to begin with, you can of course leave `rows_list` alone and build the DataFrame with the year, month, day columns from the beginning. Sorting is still easy:

```
df.sort(['year', 'month', 'day'])
```

Comment: thanks. but I am converting the strings to int. I have edited the question to include the code for creating order_array. look forward to your help

Comment: @user2842122 - those 'ints' are being converted back to strings.  unutbu - I think the simplest solution here might be to introduce a NumPy recarray, composed of a NumPy [datetime object](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) and your remaining string and integer data.  There's [a complete example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16618557/122022).

Comment: @AronAhmadia: Thank you for the comment! Yes, I was thinking of adding something like that, but I fear this answer is too long already, and Pandas is still probably the better way to go.

Comment: When you've got a hammer in your hand everything looks like a nail :)  I agree that as part of the SciPy stack, Pandas should be available and has a friendlier interface for this sort of work.

Comment: @unutbu: many thanks for the lucid explanation and the various solutions. Although the "rows_list.sort" solution seems the easiest for me to implement, i have taken your suggestion and used pandas- instead of numpy arrays- to resolve. I had one doubt though - for both the rows_list.sort and pandas solution you have first converted my three columns(yyyy,mm,dd) to one datetime column. Why is that? Is it so that the sorting can be done on just one column instead of three? Bcos it does create a problem since my final array has to have three columns (yyyy, mm, dd) instead of one.

Comment: @user2842122: Although it was not strictly necessary to convert the first three columns into a date, doing so is usually a good thing to do. First, it validates that what you have is a date ((2008,99,1) would not be a valid date). Secondly, some operations, such as sorting is easier to express when working with a date column rather than 3 integer-valued columns, since you just say `df.sort(['date']` instead of `df.sort(['year', 'month', 'day'])`.

Comment: That might seem like a little thing, but improvement to readability can add up to a big benefit over a large body of code. It also lifts you a bit further away from nitty-gritty details, and closer to expressing *intention* rather than *implementation* in code. That's one of the great attractions of using a high-level language like Python.

Comment: I've added some code above to show how to convert the `date` column to `year`, `month`, `day` columns. That way, if you choose, you could work with a `date` column for the majority of your code, and convert to 3 columns at the end if you really need it.