# Combine array of indices with array of values

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array in the following form where the first two columns are supposed to be indices of a 2-dimensional array and the following columns are arbitrary values.

```
data = np.array([[ 0. ,  1. , 48. ,  4. ],
                 [ 1. ,  2. , 44. ,  4.4],
                 [ 1. ,  1. , 34. ,  2.3],
                 [ 0. ,  2. , 55. ,  2.2],
                 [ 0. ,  0. , 42. ,  2. ],
                 [ 1. ,  0. , 22. ,  1. ]])
```

How do I combine the indices `data[:,:2]` with their values `data[:,2:]` such that the resulting array is accessible by the indices in the first two columns.

In my example that would be:

```
result = np.array([[[42. ,  2. ], [48. ,  4. ], [55. ,  2.2]],
                   [[22. ,  1. ], [34. ,  2.3], [44. ,  4.4]]])
```

I know that there is a trivial solution using python loops. But performance is a concern since I'm dealing with a huge amount of data. Specifically it's output of another program that I need to process.

Maybe there is a relatively trivial numpy solution as well. But I'm kind of stuck.

If it helps the following can be safely assumed:

- All numbers in the first two columns are whole numbers (although the array consists of floats).
- Every possible index (or rather combinations of indices) in the original array is used exactly once. I.e. there is guaranteed to be exactly one entry of the form `[i, j, ...]`.
- The indices start at 0 and I know the highest indices beforehand.

## Edit:

Hmm. I see now how my example is misleading. The truth is that some of my input arrays are sorted, but that's unreliable. So I shouldn't assume anything about the order. I reordered some rows in my example to make it clearer. In case anyone wants to make sense of the answer and comment below: In my original question the array appeared to be sorted by the first two columns.

Comment: If *data* is sorted by indices and *result* is regular `data[:,2:].reshape(-1,int(data[:,1].max() + 1),2)`, otherwise please include a more realistic example.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Thanks for the hint. I clarified my question.

Comment: For the new requirements sort before reshape `data[np.lexsort(data[:,[1,0]].T)]`.

Comment: `numba.njit` an iterative solution would work without sorting *data* if performance is the priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find `row`, `column`, `depth` base your data array, then fill like below:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[ 0. ,  0. , 42. ,  2. ],
                 [ 0. ,  1. , 48. ,  4. ],
                 [ 0. ,  2. , 55. ,  2.2],
                 [ 1. ,  0. , 22. ,  1. ],
                 [ 1. ,  1. , 34. ,  2.3],
                 [ 1. ,  2. , 44. ,  4.4]])

row = int(max(data[:,0]))+1
col = int(max(data[:,1]))+1
depth = len(data[0, 2:])

out = np.zeros([row, col, depth])

out = data[:, 2:].reshape(row,col,depth)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[[42.   2. ]
  [48.   4. ]
  [55.   2.2]]

 [[22.   1. ]
  [34.   2.3]
  [44.   4.4]]]
```

Comment: My input array isn't necessarily sorted (see my edit). I could of course sort the array first like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46230001/3139807
I thought there might be a more efficient way that doesn't require sorting. But I guess it still beats looping over the array by a lot. So I'm sticking with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numba in no-python parallel mode with loops (which is inherently for python loops acceleration) that will be one of the most efficient methods in terms of performance as [szczesny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14277722/michael-szczesny) mentioned in the comments, that won't need to sort; this code is adjusted for when column counts are `2`, if it be changeable, this code can be modified to handle that:

```
# without signature --> @nb.njit(parallel=True)
@nb.njit("float64[:, :, ::1](float64[:, ::1])", parallel=True)
def numba_(data):
    data_ = data[:, :2].astype(np.int8)
    res = np.empty((data_[:, 0].max() + 1, data_[:, 1].max() + 1, 2))
    for i in nb.prange(data_.shape[0]):
        res[data_[i, 0], data_[i, 1], 0] = data[i, 2]
        res[data_[i, 0], data_[i, 1], 1] = data[i, 3]
    return res
```

without the sorting and curing the [proposed NumPy code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72839911/13394817) (`horizontal axis --> data.shape[0]`):

[image]

More general to consider more than 2 columns:

```
@nb.njit("float64[:, :, ::1](float64[:, ::1])", parallel=True)
def numba_(data):
    data_ = data[:, :2].astype(np.int8)
    assert data_.shape[0] == data.shape[0]
    depth = data[:, 2:].shape[1]
    res = np.empty((data_[:, 0].max() + 1, data_[:, 1].max() + 1, depth))
    for i in nb.prange(data_.shape[0]):
        for j in range(depth):
            res[data_[i, 0], data_[i, 1], j] = data[i, j + 2]
    return res
```