# python numpy vec datetime64

Tags: python, django, numpy

I'm trying to write to numPy matrix a date in numpy.datetime64.

**The command**:

```
date_vec[row][ind] = np.datetime64(row[date_ind][ind], dtype='datetime64')
```

**Returns**:

```
TypeError: "Cannot cast NumPy timedelta64 scalar from metadata [us] to  according to the rule 'same_kind'"
```

The `np.datetime64(row[date_ind][ind], dtype='datetime64')` returns:

```
numpy.datetime64('2004-10-19T10:23:54.000000+0200')
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What are `date_vec[row][ind]` and `row[date_ind][ind]`?

Comment: The date_vec[row][ind] defined by:
 date_vec[row][ind]  = np.empty((MAX_SAMPLES, NUM), dtype=datetime64)

Both MAX_SAMPLES, NUM are int.. 
The row[date_ind][ind] is datetime.datetime
(Pdb) p row[date_ind][ind]
datetime.datetime(2004, 10, 19, 8, 23, 54, tzinfo=<UTC>)

Comment: I don't know. But can you post more code? I will try your code and see if it raises error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for any whom try to help me :)
I've just found [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618499/numpy-datetime64-in-recarray) 
The short solution was different instantiate of the array:

```
date_vec = zeros((MAX_A,NUM_OF_B),dtype=[('i',np.int),('date','datetime64[D]')])
```